# Bootstrap button with a badge counter not working

Tags: mysql, laravel, bootstrap-4

I have a Bootstrap button with a badge counter (a numerical indicator of how many items are associated with the link).

```
<a href="{{ route('events.index', ['group_id' => $group->id])}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Events <span class="badge badge-light">{{ $events = Event::where(['status' => 0])->count() }}</span></a>
```

The link works OK, but the badge counter isn't working. It should check how many `events` are in the database and show that number on the badge counter. So, something is wrong with this line:

```
{{ $events = Event::where(['status' => 0])->count() }}
```

I tried adding to my Events controller

```
 public function events()
    {
        return view('groups.index', [
            'count' => Event::where(['status' => 0])->count(),
        ]);
    }
```

and calling `{{ $count }}`

but I get this error

`Call to a member function count() on null (View: C:\laragon\www\version2\resources\views\groups\index.blade.php)`

Note: The button needs to count the number of event, but the button itself shows on the groups.index page (mentioned for clarity)!

Comment: is `Event` an Eloquent Model?

Comment: Yikes, I'm not sure, am pretty new to this and my friend coded parts of it. How do I check that?

Comment: it should be class `Event` which extends `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`

Comment: Yes, in my Events model I have ```use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;```

Comment: ok, now dump your data. before you return view, try `dd(Event::where(['status' => 0])->get())`

Comment: Ok, the button pill link is now ```<span class="badge badge-light">{{ dd(Event::where(['status' => 0])->get()) }}</span>``` and I get error ```Call to undefined method Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher::where() (View: C:\laragon\www\version2\resources\views\groups\index.blade.php)```

Comment: could it be the issue with my Events controller, I have the ```public function events()``` with the code inserted, but maybe it should go into the public function index() section?

Comment: use `\App\Event` or add `use`. i've edited my answer

Comment: I already had ```App\Event; ``` in my model. Question, where you specify ```public function someMethod()```, should I name the method ```events```?

Comment: you can name it absolutely however you want, except names which will override parent methods

Answer (score -1):

Extract logic in controller.

```php
use \App\Event; // use your model

public function someMethod()
{
    // other code

    return view('some.view', [
        'count' => Event::where(['status' => 0])->count(),
    ]);
}
```

view:

```html
<a href="{{ route('events.index', ['group_id' => $group->id])}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Events <span class="badge badge-light">{{ $count }}</span></a>
```

Comment: Thanks. I get an error (see my amended description above)

Comment: is it worked. i seems same as the following quetions.

Comment: at first, logic is extracted from view. secondly, `use` mentioned, which might be problem